# PHP date format for comparing date and time?

Tags: php, date

I am wondering what would be the best date and time format that php can compare later to other dates?

I am trying to do 3 things. Get the date and time,  Add 24 hours to the date and time, and later compare that number to the current date and time to verify t has not been 24 hours.

```
//GET CURRENT DATE AND TIME
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
//ADD 24 HOURS
$end_date = $date + 24;

//LATER COMPARE THE CURRENT DATE AND TIME TO MY END_DATE
if (date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()) > $end_date){
ehco "YOU ARE PAST YOUR TIME";
}else{
echo "still time left";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// now + 1 day (24h)
$end_date = strtotime("+1 day");


    //LATER COMPARE THE CURRENT DATE AND TIME TO MY END_DATE
    if (strtotime("now") > $end_date){
    ehco "YOU ARE PAST YOUR TIME";
    }else{
    echo "still time left";
    }
```

you can see the reference [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

If you need to print the value in a readable format you can use the function [DATE](http://php.net/date)

`date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$end_date);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not parse the time in to a timestamp, then just compare. There is a magical function called [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using unix timestamps and you can add 24 hours like so:

```
$date = time();
$endDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('Y'));
//LATER COMPARE THE CURRENT DATE AND TIME TO MY END_DATE
if ($date > $endDate) {
    ehco "YOU ARE PAST YOUR TIME";
} else {
    echo "still time left";
}
```

By using timestamps it's just a matter of comparing two integers to see which one is greater than the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ISO standard date time, they will sort alphabetically. E.g.:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```